# How do I update an existing older rails project to a newer version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails project using rails 3.0.7.

I want to update it to 3.1.0.rc6.

However the directory structure of these are really different,

is there an automatic way to transfer the directory structure? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a github project to track the difference of the default generated project layout of rails
https://github.com/pmq20/rails-diff-track

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an automated way to update Rails apps to 3.1, but I found David Rice's blog entry about to be a pretty good overview of the steps involved. You can find the overview at: http://davidjrice.co.uk/2011/05/25/how-to-upgrade-a-rails-application-to-version-3-1-0.html